# Cassandra:2.2.8:org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses

Tags: cassandra

I'm experiencing node crashes where system.logfile is showing bunch of 'ReadTimeoutException' hitting 500ms.

cassandra.yaml file has setting for [read_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000]

can you folks please share how i can address these timeout! Thanks in advance!

## error stack:

ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-241] 2017-02-01 13:18:27,663 Message.java:611 - Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0x5d8abf33, /172.18.30.62:47580 => /216.12.225.9:9042]
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraRoleManager.getRole(CassandraRoleManager.java:497) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraRoleManager.canLogin(CassandraRoleManager.java:306) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.ClientState.login(ClientState.java:269) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.messages.AuthResponse.execute(AuthResponse.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:507) [apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:401) [apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$700(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:32) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$8.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164) [apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105) [apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.ReadCallback.get(ReadCallback.java:110) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractReadExecutor.get(AbstractReadExecutor.java:147) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.fetchRows(StorageProxy.java:1441) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.readRegular(StorageProxy.java:1365) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.read(StorageProxy.java:1282) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.execute(SelectStatement.java:224) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.execute(SelectStatement.java:176) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraRoleManager.getRoleFromTable(CassandraRoleManager.java:505) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraRoleManager.getRole(CassandraRoleManager.java:493) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        ... 13 common frames omitted

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2017-02-01 13:18:27,682 MessagingService.java:946 - READ messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 149 for internal timeout and 0 for cross node timeout
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-02-01 13:18:27,693 StatusLogger.java:106 - enterprise.t_sf_venue_test                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2017-02-01 13:18:27,699 MessagingService.java:946 - REQUEST_RESPONSE messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 7 for internal timeout and 0 for cross node timeout
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-02-01 13:18:27,699 StatusLogger.java:106 - enterprise.alestnstats                    0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2017-02-01 13:18:27,699 MessagingService.java:946 - RANGE_SLICE messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 116 for internal timeout and 0 for cross node timeout

Comment: Can you post your query, as well as how many rows you are expecting to get back?

Comment: hi there. thanks for taking my question. i'm trying to pin the query though i am wondering why read timeout are occurring at 5000ms when read_request_timeout_in_ms is at 10000ms - is there other dial to control these read timeouts?

Comment: If you are getting query timeouts, it's usually more of a problem with the query itself, and not with the config.  But you can also set that limit at the driver level.

Answer (score 1):

As you see in your logs, actually the failing query is not the one you are trying to execute.

the [failing query](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.2.8/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/auth/CassandraRoleManager.java#L493) is internal to cassandra:

"SELECT * FROM system_auth.roles;"

These internal cassandra queries(misc queries) does not use 'read_request_timeout_in_ms'. Instead, it uses 'request_timeout_in_ms'.

Comment: thank you.. your reply was indeed helpful and i got to know more about this other parameter