# org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am getting the below error in my Cassandra Java client.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.cassandra.support.exception.CassandraConnectionFailureException: [DNS/IP:PORT] Connection has been closed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [DNS/IP:PORT] Connection has been closed
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
```

At the same time, the error in Cassandra logs is as below.

```
ERROR [Native-Transport-Requests-37] 2022-07-19 09:11:38,152 ErrorMessage.java:384 - Unexpected exception during request
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2203) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.AuthCache.get(AuthCache.java:108) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.PermissionsCache.getPermissions(PermissionsCache.java:45) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.AuthenticatedUser.getPermissions(AuthenticatedUser.java:104) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.ClientState.authorize(ClientState.java:439) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.ClientState.checkPermissionOnResourceChain(ClientState.java:368) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.ClientState.ensureHasPermission(ClientState.java:345) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.ClientState.hasAccess(ClientState.java:332) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.ClientState.hasColumnFamilyAccess(ClientState.java:310) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement.checkAccess(ModificationStatement.java:211) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.processStatement(QueryProcessor.java:221) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:255) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:240) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.messages.QueryMessage.execute(QueryMessage.java:116) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
```

Apart from CPU IO wait (spike in red below), everything (CPU usage/ memory usage/ read queries count per min etc) looks normal. There was no compaction task running at that time.

[image: cpu IO wait spike]

I checked multiple articles, questions, and bug reports online but could not find any convincing solution. Similar question: [Cassandra:2.2.8:org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985026/cassandra2-2-8org-apache-cassandra-exceptions-readtimeoutexception-operation)

Time of error - 9:11 AM
GC activities at that time were normal. GC activities were abnormal at 8:20 AM.

[image]

It's a VM and neighbours/siblings were under-utilized.

Any suggestions on what should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

This part of the stack trace indicates to me that the request failed while trying to check the auth cache for user permissions:

```
    ...
    at org.apache.cassandra.auth.AuthCache.get(AuthCache.java:108) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.auth.PermissionsCache.getPermissions(PermissionsCache.java:45) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.auth.AuthenticatedUser.getPermissions(AuthenticatedUser.java:104) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    ...
```

It is actually checking a local cache so it should be really quick. The only time I've seen an auth cache lookup timeout is when nodes are overloaded so they are unresponsive.

Check for long GCs or multiple occurrences of short GCs which add up to a long pause time. If the nodes are VMs, make sure there are no "noisy neighbours" which steal CPU cycles from the nodes. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Erick Ramirez. There were no abnormal GC activity at that time. Neighbors were under-utilized. Updated the question with this data.